# Wood installation artist from The Break-Up

Tags: props, set-design, the-break-up

Towards the end of the film, Jennifer Aniston's character lets a prospective art collector, played by Ivan Sergei, into the apartment to look at a large art installation.

It is a massive wood block bolted towards the ceiling in the entry hall of the apartment.

I've tried to find any info about this piece.  I can't even find a movie still on the internet, but I captured an image from my TV:

Would anyone know the artist of this piece?  I'm guessing maybe they are a native of Chicago.

[image: Wood Art]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reached out to the film's Set Decorator [Daniel Clancy](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0452594/fullcredits/set_decorator?ref_=m_ttfc_11). He said that the piece, along with various others in the film, was rented from a local art studio called [*The Golden Triangle*](https://goldentriangle.biz/) and hazarded that the artist was maybe Tibetan.

The owner of the art studio has responded that the piece was '*vintage*' and not by a known artist, which I think is where our trail is going to end, unless you get lucky and someone recognises it individually.

Comment: Nice!  I have seen this movie over 20 times and have always wondered what that thing was

Comment: @steelersquirrel - As answers go, this one kinda sucks. But at least we've exhausted this lead.

Comment: You put in the effort to contact the set decorator, this definitely does not suck!

Comment: Excellent.  I feared this wouldnt turn anything up.  The cred is yours.